# How do I set a basic filter in php using google sheets api?

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

Google has given me the following code template to set a basic filter. I just need an example on how I could make my php code create a conditional filter in my google sheet. can somebody help please?

```
// Filter sheet 
// TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:

$requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();


$response = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $requestBody);

// TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
echo '<pre>', var_export($response, true), '</pre>', "\n";

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice @Paul T. I'll do that next time.

Comment: That was no advice, just an edit comment, but no worries!

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a filter request using [Batch Update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) you will need first to set up [your criteria as shown in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters#filter_criteria) and then use this criteria to build [your filter representation as also indicated in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters#filter_representation).

Here is an example using some filter criteria from the documentation:

```js
// Filter sheet 
// TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:

// Set desired criteria
$criteria->{'0'} = array(
    'condition' => array(
        'type' => 'DATE_BEFORE',
        'values' => array(
            'userEnteredValue' => '4/30/2016'
        )
    )
);

// Set requests array with the appropiate criteria
$requests = [
  new Google_Service_Sheets_Request( array(
        'requests' => array(
            'setBasicFilter' => array(
                'filter' => array(
                    'range' => [ // your desired range
                        'sheetId' => 0,
                        'startColumnIndex' => 0,
                        'endColumnIndex' => 0
                    ],
                'criteria' => $criteria
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

// Add the requests to the body
$requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array('requests' => $requests));


$response = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $requestBody);

// TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
echo '<pre>', var_export($response, true), '</pre>', "\n";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @MateoRandwolf. it almost worked. I did something similar in the end.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please explain/post as an answer to your own question what did you change to solve your issue? This will help other users with similar questions to find an answer easier. Thanks ! :D