# Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field

Tags: php, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My first post, related to the following post
[How do I set a basic filter in php using google sheets api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082939/how-do-i-set-a-basic-filter-in-php-using-google-sheets-api)

I have implemented code below but get this message and I'm not sure what's the cause:

> Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.

```
$criteria = new \stdClass();
$criteria->{'2'} = array(
    'condition' => array(
        'type' => 'NUMBER_EQ',
        'values' => array(
            'userEnteredValue' => '5'
        )
    )
);

$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Sheets_Request( array(
        'requests' => array(
            'setBasicFilter' => array(
                'filter' => array(
                    'range' => [
                        'sheetId'           => 0,
                        'startRowIndex'     => 4,
                        'endRowIndex'       => 20,
                        'startColumnIndex'  => 0,
                        'endColumnIndex'    => 11
                    ],
                    'criteria' => $criteria
                ),
            ),
        'includeSpreadsheetInResponse'  => true,
        'responseIncludeGridData'       => true
        )
    )
  )
];
  
$requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array('requests' => $requests));
$response = $sheets->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $requestBody);
```

Comment: I don't know what this request is supposed to look like, but you've got an array called "requests" wrapped in a `Google_Service_Sheets_Request` and then wrapped in *another* array called "requests". Might want to confirm that's the correct way to use this.

Comment: Have you tried testing your request  parameters using the API explorer? I just noticed that your criteria array was set to 2 initially `$criteria->{'2'}`. Would it be possible if you could share a sample sheet so we might be able to replicate your issue. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- Please include `'userEnteredValue' => '5'` to an array.
- `'requests' => array(,,,)` is not required in `new Google_Service_Sheets_Request()`. Because `array('requests' => $requests)` is used.
- Please put `'includeSpreadsheetInResponse' => true,` and `'responseIncludeGridData' => true` outside of `$requests`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
$criteria = new \stdClass();
$criteria->{'2'} = array(
    'condition' => array(
        'type' => 'NUMBER_EQ',
        'values' => [array('userEnteredValue' => '5')]
    )
);
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Sheets_Request( array(
            'setBasicFilter' => array(
                'filter' => array(
                    'range' => [
                        'sheetId'           => 0,
                        'startRowIndex'     => 4,
                        'endRowIndex'       => 20,
                        'startColumnIndex'  => 0,
                        'endColumnIndex'    => 11
                    ],
                    'criteria' => $criteria
                )
            )
        )
    )
];
$requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests,
    'includeSpreadsheetInResponse' => true,
    'responseIncludeGridData' => true
));
$response = $sheets->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $requestBody);
```

- In this case, `$criteria->{'2'}` can be used, and also, `$criteria->{'1'}` instead of `$criteria->{'2'}` can be used.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [SetBasicFilterRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#setbasicfilterrequest)